# Realizing Gromov-Hausdorff convergence as Hausdorff convergence

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

I've asked this question [on Math Stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4177211/realizing-gromov-hausdorff-convergence-as-hausdorff-convergence), but since there was no answer I thought that perhaps it is not written down. I hope this is appropriate for this site.

I know that given two metric spaces $X$ and $Y$, one can realize the Gromov-Hausdorff metric between the spaces as the Hausdorff distance between $\tilde{X},\tilde{Y}$ as subsets of $X\sqcup Y$. Given a sequence of metric spaces $(X_n,d_n)$ such that $X_n\overset{\mathrm{GH}}{\to}X_\infty$ (converge in the Gromov-Hausdorff sense), can we embed all the sequence isometrically $\{ X_n \}$ in a metric space $Z$ so that $$d_\mathrm{H}(\tilde{X}_n,\tilde{X}_m)=d_{\mathrm{GH}}(X_n,X_m)?,$$
where $\tilde{X}_n$ is the realization of $X_n$ in $Z$ and $d_\mathrm{H}(A,B)$ is the Hausdorff distance induced in $Z$.

I have a feeling that this is true, but I haven't found a place where this is implied or explicitly stated. I'm assuming that if there is a counter-example, it should be something relatively simple I haven't considered. I attach some questions below which might show that it is right. I'd also appreciate partial insights on the matter.

---

**Auxiliary questions**

I know that if a space $(Z,d)$ is second countable and complete, that the Hausdorff distance on compact subsets is complete. So if $X_n$ are compact metric subsets, then it seems reasonable that if I can embed them appropriately in some complete $(Z,d)$, then $X$ would be embedded in $Z$ by the completeness of $d_\mathrm{H}$ (Hausdorff-distance). So I would like to ask three easier questions:

1. Given $N$ compact metric spaces, $\{(X_n,d_n) \}_{n=1}^N$, can we find by an iterative process embed them in $Z_N:=\underset{n=1}{ \overset{N}{\bigsqcup}   }X_n$ such that their differnces from one another in the Gromov-Hausdorff distance agree with their Hausdorff distance of subsets of $Z_N$?
2. If 1 is true for every $N$, can we take the direct limits of the metric spaces, obtain a metric space $Z$ in which all embedding agree with the Gromov-Hausdorff distance?
3. Can we take the completion of $Z$ and then ensure that $X_\infty$ be isometric to a subset of $Z$?

Comment: What if you just have 3 spaces, $X_0, X_1, X_2$ -- can you embed them isometrically in some $Z$ so that $d_{GH}(X_i,X_j) = d_H(\tilde X_i , \tilde X_j)$? If you can do that, then you can probably do the whole sequence...

Comment: @TimCampion Are you saying that if this question for three spaces, then the answer to questions $1$ and $2$ is yes, or just for $1$? Just so that I better understand your comment.

Comment: I suppose I just mean (1), but even then it's not immediate, just seems like it will probably be easy to generalize.